# Cyber Security - recommended reading

Tags: reference-request

I'm applying for a doctoral training in Cyber Security, although I come from a maths background. I've been told that my background meets the entry criteria, although for my application I would like to be able to say that I've looked into Cyber Security it at least some detail.

Given that I will have very little time to do any reading before applying (about 2 weeks), what would you recommend I read? A few chapters from an academic text, or a popular book on the topic?

Specific book/paper recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: First hint: don't use the word “cyber”. Second hint: don't lie on your application. In two weeks, you cannot claim to have looked at a broad topic in any detail. Third hint: do read Ross Anderson's book.

Comment: Thanks for your second and third hints, although I don't really understand the first one. Why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a peek at Anderson's classic ["Security Engineering"](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~rja14/book.html) (PDF legally available for free at the link). It won't help you with the details, but it gives an overview of the whole area, for (more or less) laypeople.